Time a particular function in a module
I have a module with an entry point function which itself calls many other functions (call these sub-functions calls).
I would like to time a particular sub-function. But I can't edit the code of the module to actually time the sub-function.
Is there a context-manager I could use to time the sub-function without modifying the module code?
Example:
I have a module foo.py like this:
def A():
    sleep(1)
    return B()

def B():
    sleep(2)


I can't modify foo.py but I want to time the B() call in function A when I call it from a script which I can modify.
I imagine a solution like:
with timepatch('foo.B') as timer:
    foo.A()
print(timer.elpased_time)

which would print "2" because B() took 2 seconds. However I don't know if the timepatch object exists. Do you know anything of the sort over than profiling the whole execution?

This library may allow me to achieve the desired result: https://github.com/dlshriver/intercepts
